# How to design a server that does not interrupt downloads?

Tags: web-development, node.js, file-handling

I'm building a Node server that serves large files for download and streaming. It will be necessary to modify these files on occasion, sometimes in bulk with a script. I want to be able to update them without interrupting downloads in progress.

What I've come up with is a system where for a given file's database entry, I'll have an "in use" flag, and an "updating" flag. I'll need to set the "in use" flag to true when a download begins, and somehow emit an event that sets the flag to false whenever the last download completes.

The "updating" flag will prevent any further downloads. When I initiate a script to update the files, it will first change a given file's "updating" flag to true, then check the "in use" flag. If it is true, it will register a listener for the last download complete event mentioned above, which will update the file.

My question is, is this completely crazy? Is there a common pattern for this problem?

Comment: Once a download has started, does your server need to consult the database, or even access the file being downloaded by name? Or are you at that point just accessing the file using a file-handle retrieved from the OS?

Comment: For one similar common crazy pattern see [Stack Overflow: Node.js on multi-core machines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines) and [Stack Overflow: A version of node.js that is multi-threaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613357/a-version-of-node-js-that-is-multi-threaded) to name just some representatives of the _same_ question

Comment: Could you create a copy of the file? That way, the old downloads can continue and once you're finished with your update, you switch over to the new file for future downloads.

Comment: @xmojmr - Those questions are not event slightly related. I'm already using multiple server instances with a load balancer.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - A database is consulted in order to find the location of a given file.

Comment: @StefanSchmidt - I'd still need to clean up the old one while ensuring that the current downloads were not interrupted (the files are multiple GB). It would also increase storage requirements. This would make the transition faster though.

Comment: @TomO'Connell if you already have several concurrent mutually not-blocking processing queues, then the questions I've linked may be _"not event slightly related"_. The concurrency aspect of your architecture is not obvious from your question. The thing that you describe as "_modify these files on occasion_" seems to be simple typical create another file, write to temp and do quick atomic rename afterwards. I don't see any _crazy_ problem here. Maybe some `UML Sequence Diagram` might make your problem/question clearer

Comment: @xmojmr - So in you're basically restating what StefanSchmidt suggested above. Great, thank you for your fantastic wisdom.

Comment: @TomO'Connell I've posted my comment 2 hours sooner than Stefan. If we both came to same or similar conclusion then perhaps there is something to it. I don't understand your attacking tone an I'm sort-of black listing you from any further help attempts. Good luck

Comment: @TomO'Connell: If you are using a *nix-based server, the filesystem will normally cleanup a removed file after the last reference to it is removed. Both directory entries and open filehandles count as references here, so the file could have been removed from the directory while there are still active downloads of it without affecting those downloads.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - I'm using Ubuntu. Are there any different implications for the download if I were to overwrite the old file vs removing it?

Comment: @TomO'Connell: In-place modification of the file would affect the running downloads, as they would partially see the modifications. Making modifications by writing a new file and re-pointing the directory entry would not affect the running downloads.